# No puedo instalar paquetes en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

He tenido problemas con la instalación de paquetes en RStudio, no sé a qué se deba, instalé el programa de RStudio hace dos semanas aproximadamente y ya para comenzarlo a trabajar en clase no me permite instalar ningún paquete, me aparecen mensajes de error como este:

> install.packages("readxl")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Angie Camacho/OneDrive - UDEP/Documentos/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/readxl_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1662830 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

Por favor, en serio necesito ayuda urgente, no puedo avanzar en clase porque RStudio no instala los paquetes que necesito para trabajar. Es urgente, este curso es muy importante para mí y no lo podré aprender si no soluciono este problema. De corazón si alguien me puede ayudar, por favor dejar su mensaje y comunicarse conmigo.

Agradecida desde ya, quedo pendiente a alguna respuesta, bendiciones.[image: Aquí dejo una imagen del problema explicado en el mensaje]

Answer (score 2):

En Windows normalmente cuando se instala un paquete, se descargan las versiones binarias, es decir ya compiladas, pero aún así, ciertos paquetes, cuando la versión de R del sistema difiere de la versión de R para la cual fue compilado el paquete a descargar, se descarga el paquete en su versión de código fuente. En los casos dónde el código fuente no es código R, por ejemplo: C, C++ o fortran, se debe "recompilar" localmente el código. Este pareciera ser tu caso, según entiendo, tienes un R versión 4.1x y la instalación de los últimos paquetes apuntan a la versión 4.2x. Hay algunas formas de solucionarlo:

1. Instalar la última versión de R (en tu caso 4.2): Esto eventualmente tiene el problema de toda nueva versión: deberás reinstalar toda la paquetería que tienes actualmente, aunque hay formas de automatizarlo no deja de ser un trabajo que lleva tiempo.
2. Instalar [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), en tu caso sería la versión 4.0, tener en cuenta la arquitectura que corresponda 32 o 64 bits. Teniendo correctamente instalado esto, cuando actualices o instales una versión de `readxl`, se debería descargar el código fuente y automáticamente recompilarse todo el código no R del paquete para la versión 4.1, debiera ser un proceso transparente, solo toma un poco más de tiempo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude solucionar el problema de RStudio, estoy muy emocionada porque al fin podré trabajarlo de la mano con RCommander. Al parecer todo se habría debido a una mala instalación de paquetes y a la ubicación de mis archivos. Bendiciones y gracias a tod@s por su ayuda.